# Issue with CSV formatting from web scrape

Tags: python, loops, csv, beautifulsoup

I wrote the below script to scrape some data from download.com:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

query = raw_input("Please enter the query value: ")
limit = raw_input("Please enter the results limit (1-100): ")
minreview = raw_input("Please enter the min user rating (1-5): ")
maxreview = raw_input("Please enter the max user rating (1-5): ")
csvname = raw_input("Enter a filename.csv for CSV output: ")

cnetFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/softwareProductSearch?partKey=APIKEYGOESHERE&partTag=APIKEYGOESHERE&query=" + query + "$
cnetXml = cnetFile.read()
cnetFile.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(cnetXml, features="xml")
#print soup.prettify()

f = csv.writer(open(csvname, "w"))
f.writerow(["Name", "Link", "Mfg", "Mfg Link", "Price", "Downloads", "User Rating Summary", "User Rating Product"])

data = soup.find_all(['Name', 'Price', 'TotalDownloads', 'LinkURL', 'Rating'])
#print data

for x in data:
        strip1 = x.contents
        print strip1
        f.writerow(strip1)
```

The output of the CSV looks like this for returning 2 products:  (There should be eight fields returned for each product like in the headers in the code but occasionally one is missing like the eighth one in the 1st product under the "2".)

```
Name,Link,Mfg,Mfg Link,Price,Downloads,User Rating Summary,User Rating Product

Firegraphic

http://www.download.com/firegraphic/3000-2192_4-10367545.html?tag=api

Firegraphic

http://www.firegraphic.com

$49.95

2546868

2.0



MP3 CD Maker

http://www.download.com/mp3-cd-maker/3000-2140_4-10065486.html?tag=api

ZY Computing

http://www.dvdsanta.com

$24.95

1653394

2.0

2.0
```

Here is an example of the data in the soup variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CNETResponse realm="cnet" version="1.0" xmlns="http://developer.api.cnet.com/re
st/v1.0/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<SoftwareProducts numFound="898" numReturned="2" start="0">
<SoftwareProduct id="11889531" setId="10367545" xlink:href="http://developer.api
.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/softwareProduct?productSetId=10367545&amp;iod=userRatings&am
p;partKey=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys&amp;partTag=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys">
<Name>Firegraphic</Name>
<Version>11.0</Version>
<LinkURL>http://www.download.com/firegraphic/3000-2192_4-10367545.html?tag=api</
LinkURL>
<Publisher id="6268727">
<Name>Firegraphic</Name>
<LinkURL>http://www.firegraphic.com</LinkURL>
<UrsRegId/>
</Publisher>
<License>Free to try</License>
<BetaRelease>false</BetaRelease>
<Price currency="USD">$49.95</Price>
<Summary>Import, organize, view, edit, print, and share your digital images.</Su
mmary>
<Description>&lt;p&gt;Firegraphic is an image viewer for photography professiona
ls, Web, and graphic designers to import, organize, view, edit, print, and share
 their digital images. The new Firegraphic has improved its memory usage and con
sumes very low memory, which leaves more memory for you to edit your photos in t
he image editor. Firegraphic now supports the RAW file formats from digital came
ras. Firegraphic gives you the ability to open multiple photos in the Viewer and
 compare photos side-by-side to choose your best shot. You also can customize th
e tools in your toolbar and the Context menu in the Viewer. The Firegraphic user
 interface lets you change the skin color and edit photos with a third-party ima
ge editor.&lt;/p&gt;</Description>
<WhatsNew/>
<Requirements> </Requirements>
<Platform>Windows</Platform>
<OperatingSystems>
<OperatingSystem id="3">Windows</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="17">Windows 2000</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="25">Windows XP</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="43">Windows 2003</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="52">Windows Vista</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="133">Windows 7</OperatingSystem>
</OperatingSystems>
<EditorsRating outOf="5">3.0</EditorsRating>
<EditorsNote/>
<PreferredNode id="2192"/>
<WeeklyDownloads>8</WeeklyDownloads>
<TotalDownloads>2546868</TotalDownloads>
<CreatedDate>2011-04-21 17:41:19.0</CreatedDate>
<ReleaseDate>2011-04-21 00:00:00.0</ReleaseDate>
<ReviewDate>2008-11-09 00:00:00.0</ReviewDate>
<Limitations>30-day trial</Limitations>
<BuyNowUrl type=""> </BuyNowUrl>
<TrialPayUrl/>
<CleverBridgeUrl/>
<UpsellUnit/>
<ButtonPartner/>
<CNETContentIds/>
<FileSize>8358576</FileSize>
<Category id="2192" xlink:href="http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/category
?categoryId=2192&amp;siteId=4&amp;partKey=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys&amp;partTag=5
72kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys"/>
<UserRatingSummary>
<Rating outOf="5">2.0</Rating>
<TotalVotes>7</TotalVotes>
</UserRatingSummary>
<UserRatingProduct>
<Rating outOf="5"/>
<TotalVotes>0</TotalVotes>
</UserRatingProduct>
<EditorsPick/>
<ListingType>STANDARD</ListingType>
</SoftwareProduct>
<SoftwareProduct id="10296367" setId="10065486" xlink:href="http://developer.api
.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/softwareProduct?productSetId=10065486&amp;iod=userRatings&am
p;partKey=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys&amp;partTag=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys">
<Name>MP3 CD Maker</Name>
<Version>2.0</Version>
<LinkURL>http://www.download.com/mp3-cd-maker/3000-2140_4-10065486.html?tag=api<
/LinkURL>
<Publisher id="83016">
<Name>ZY Computing</Name>
<LinkURL>http://www.dvdsanta.com</LinkURL>
<UrsRegId/>
</Publisher>
<License>Free to try</License>
<BetaRelease>false</BetaRelease>
<Price currency="USD">$24.95</Price>
<Summary>Create audio CDs from your MP3 collection.</Summary>
<Description>&lt;p&gt;MP3 CD Maker works with a CD recorder to create audio CDs
from collections of MP3 audio files. It directly converts MP3 files into the CD
audio format and can decode any MP3 file into WAV or raw audio. A normalization
feature lets you ensure that all MP3s in a set have the same volume level. &lt;/
p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Version 2.0 adds support for 200 more CD-R/RW drives.&lt;/p&gt;</D
escription>
<WhatsNew/>
<Requirements>Windows 95/98/Me/NT/2000/XP</Requirements>
<Platform>Windows</Platform>
<OperatingSystems>
<OperatingSystem id="3">Windows</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="5">Windows 95</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="8">Windows NT</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="6">Windows 98</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="7">Windows Me</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="17">Windows 2000</OperatingSystem>
<OperatingSystem id="25">Windows XP</OperatingSystem>
</OperatingSystems>
<EditorsRating outOf="5">4.0</EditorsRating>
<EditorsNote/>
<PreferredNode id="2140"/>
<WeeklyDownloads>103</WeeklyDownloads>
<TotalDownloads>1653394</TotalDownloads>
<CreatedDate>2004-06-16 19:07:46.0</CreatedDate>
<ReleaseDate>2004-06-16 00:00:00.0</ReleaseDate>
<ReviewDate>2009-02-27 00:00:00.0</ReviewDate>
<Limitations>limited to 4 songs on a CD</Limitations>
<BuyNowUrl type="dl_buy_ond">http://send.onenetworkdirect.net/z/126524/CD103284/
</BuyNowUrl>
<TrialPayUrl/>
<CleverBridgeUrl/>
<UpsellUnit/>
<ButtonPartner/>
<CNETContentIds/>
<FileSize>1283187</FileSize>
<Category id="2140" xlink:href="http://developer.api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/category
?categoryId=2140&amp;siteId=4&amp;partKey=572kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys&amp;partTag=5
72kjgq8h2mqbsup36cubkys"/>
<UserRatingSummary>
<Rating outOf="5">2.0</Rating>
<TotalVotes>3</TotalVotes>
</UserRatingSummary>
<UserRatingProduct>
<Rating outOf="5">2.0</Rating>
<TotalVotes>3</TotalVotes>
</UserRatingProduct>
<EditorsPick/>
<ListingType>STANDARD</ListingType>
</SoftwareProduct>
</SoftwareProducts>
</CNETResponse>
```

How can I fix my loop so that the data for the first product returned will go into the 8 columns    across and then each subsequent product will start on a new row and the data going across for each one?

Thanks!

---

Based on Birei's help, I was able to get the data going across and I figured out how to start a new row after every 8 items returned with this code:

```
strip1 = []
for y in data:
    strip1.extend(y.contents)
    print strip1
for x in xrange(0,len(strip1),8):
    f.writerow(strip1[x:x+8])
```

The only problem I have left is that, sometimes the find_all for 'Rating' pulls 2 ratings and sometimes only 1 rating.  That messes up my start a new row every 8 since sometimes there are only 7 items returned.  How do I print "none" in the 2nd 'Rating' if only 1 rating is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writerow()` for the data as you already have for the header. You won't need to transform anything as `contents` property returns a list:

```
for x in data:
    strip1 = x.contents
    f.writerow(strip1)
```

**EDIT**: If above solution does not work because `contents` returns one element each time, try to save them to an array and print it at the end:

```
strip1 = []
for x in data:
    strip1.extend(x.contents)
f.writerow(strip1)
```

---

**NEW EDIT**: After looking at your `xml` file, my approach would be to loop throught every `<SoftwareProduct>` elements and extract the fields you want from there, like:

```
for product in soup.find_all('SoftwareProduct'):
    strip1 = []
    strip1.extend(product.Name.contents)
    strip1.extend(product.Price.contents)
    ...
    f.writerow(strip1)
```

Comment: The header is how I want it but the issue I am having is that my data is not populating across in the columns.  It is populating down into rows.

Comment: @Christopher: Does `writerow()` add its field in different lines too?

Comment: Yes, the first writerow with the header info is going across into separate columns.  The second writerow with the data is going straight down into rows and not across into the columns.

Comment: Can you provide what is the `url` you are scrapping?

Comment: The url is in the cnetFile variable but you would need an API key to pull the data down.

Comment: I tried with it but could not access. I wanted to debug it with real data but I see that it's not possible.

Comment: @Christopher: I've updated the answer but it's a shot in the dark without data to test. I hope it can be closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks and that did help me.  I added a section to my question above with the remaining issue I have left if you have some thoughts on that.

Comment: Everything is working great now.  I hadn't noticed the SoftwareProduct tag enclosing each one so that really helped.  Thanks again for the assistance on this, I appreciate it!